# Возможно ли в Django передать файл (style.css например) через префикс (псевдоним ссылки) '<int:style_id>/'

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! хотел сделать так чтобы при просмотре исходного кода страницы не было прямых ссылок в корень сайта (в целях безопасности - после опыта с PHP, взломов, кражей денег меня замкнуло на этом вопросе  ) и пока не получается это сделать, незнаю может это всё лишнее, но возник вопрос - как можно в Django передать текст файла (или сам файл) через префикс. Создал отдельный app для этого назвал style_css и получилось примерно вот так:

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name = 'style_css'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:style_id>/', views.style_css, name='style'),

]
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

def style_css(request, style_id):
    my_file = open("style_css/style/style.css", "r")

    file = my_file.read(id=style_id)
    context = {
        'style': file,
    }

    return render(request, context)
```

**base.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Тестовая старница</title>
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% url "style_css:style" style_css.id %}'>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <p><a href="{% url 'logs:index' %}">
    Журнал записей пользователя
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}{{ user.username }}{% endif %}
    </a></p>
</div>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

*при обновлении страницы выводит ошибку:*

**Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'style' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[^/]+)/$']**

Может кто знает как сделать чтоб вывод файлов из корня сайта происходил через префикс?

Comment: Так для этого статические файлы и придумали

Answer (score 0):

1. Судя по ошибке у вас не передаётся `style_css`, для подстановки `style_css.id`
2. Ну и смотрите комментарий Александра
3. А вот это строчку я вообще не понимаю:

```
file = my_file.read(id=style_id)
```

У метода read нет именованного аргумента id.

Простите, но что вы написали?